# Phil has Phound a Saphe

Tags: number-sequence

> Phil has phound a secret room
>   Hiding in his basement.
>   On the saphe within that room:
>   Numbers slight phaded.
>   Every combination tried
>   Phailed to crack it open.
>   Can you phind the phive digits?
>   Help Phil hit the big one.

[image]

<sub>Transcription to ensure clarity: 6463-8473-3344-4866-3749</sub>

Comment: Shouldn't that be a Wells Phargo Co. Bank saphe?

Comment: I swear 8473 should be 84733. -- Wait, disregard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously this requires an outside object:

> a phone (hence all the "ph"s in the clue).  Numbers in the clue correspond to letters from a phone's keypad.

Also one element is a red herring:

> Disregard the dashes

6463-8473-3344-4866-3749

> NINE- THRE-E EIG-HT ON-E SIX

For an answer oph:

> 93816

Comment: Also, the first letters spell "PHONEPCH".  Phone is obvious, but I'm not sure if PCH is supposed to mean something, unless it's a vague reference to a [PCH Chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub#Langwell) which was used on some smartphones, at some point.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I am not knowledgeable enough about chipsets to include a reference to PCH. It is a coincidence.

Comment: @EngineerToast I figured that it was a coincidence, but it was an amusing one, nontheless. =D